# How do I get rid of `requested insecure font` error message?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, https, fonts

I'm getting this error message in the console when I run my app:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/rosarivo/v1/OGdIq-p0tOtBN2VMVvO9W_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

It doesn't affect functionality of the app, but Chrome thinks it's insecure because it's trying to load these insecure fonts.

I would change all the loaded fonts from `http://` to `https://`, but I have no idea where they appear in the code. I didn't put any google fonts in this app, and I'm not really sure why this error message is happening at all.

Any ideas where this might be stemming from and how I can get rid of this error message?

Thanks!

Edit:

The error points to my index.html file. This is it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta https-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>The App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "but I have no idea where they appear in the code" - figuring this out is your only solution. Maybe it's a CSS file that requires the fonts.

Comment: It's not a CSS file that requires the fonts. Is it possible it's in the node modules folder? If so, how can I search for them in vscode?

Comment: Do you control this code? If so, just search your files for any mention of "rosarivo", and fix things there.

Comment: It could be requested by any node packages that you are using, as @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans suggests search the entire folder to see which code is sending the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be with my browser. Tried in a few other browsers and devices and works fine. Now I still get the error messages, but the app is marked "secure" next to the url. So mission accomplished I guess